# How to test a function with input() call (unittest)

Tags: python, unit-testing, input, mocking

I want to test the following module. There are hundreds of similar modules, and the test data for each module is stored on `input_suffix.txt` and `output_suffix.txt` (`suffix` is the name of the module).

```
def func(data):
    # do something
    return something

def reader():
    for case_no in range(int(input())):
        n_rows, n_cols = map(int, input().strip('\n').split())
        data = [[int(n) for n in input().strip('\n').split()] for _ in range(n_rows)]
        print(f'Case #{case_no + 1}: {func(data)}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader()
```

I could simply read both `input_suffix.txt` and `output_suffix.txt` files for the module to be tested, and process the input data to feed data right into the `func()` and get the job done by comparing the returned value to the expected output, which also could be processed from output data.

However, there are hundreds of similar modules, and they don't always share the same structure. The first line of `input_suffix.txt` always indicate the number of included tests, but after that, it varies all over. Sometimes, each test starts with a line that contains a number of rows(`num_rows`) and columns(`num_cols`) and the following `num_rows` lines is a representation of an array (just like the above). But `input_suffix.txt` may not have `num_rows` or an array representation at all, or may have multiple arrays, or other types of data. Likewise, arguments for the `func()` varies from module to module as well.

Because of the variations, I need to modify hundreds of test drivers to feed correctly pre-processed data to `func()` equivalents of each module. To avoid the tiresome task, these are what I need;

1. I need a way to pass the data (taken from `input_suffix.txt`) to the `input()` of each `reader()` on a line by line basis (each `reader()` of each module already has an adequate data processing scheme, so if I just pass the content of `input_suffix.txt` line by line, it will work).
2. I need a way to capture the printed data from `reader()` to compare it to the expected output taken from `output_suffix.txt`.

I have `input_suffix.txt` and `output_suffix.txt` on `i` and `o`, but I didn't know how to parse the printed value to compare it to `o`. That was the point where I was stuck, but after some trouble, I managed to get a working code. But I assume this is not the standard way for the job.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from suffix import *

class Tester(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        with open('input_suffix.txt', 'r') as f:
            i = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
        with open('output_suffix.txt', 'r') as f:
            o = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]

        m = MagicMock()
        f = StringIO()
        length = len(i)
        with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=i):
            reader()
            for _ in range(length):
                m()
        result  = f.getvalue().split('\n')[:-1]
        for case_no, (actual, expected) in enumerate(zip(result, to)):
            self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
            print(f'Test {case_no + 1} Passed')
```

Could you suggest the proper way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the input using the `patch` that is available from the `unittest` library. The simple code to mock the input from the user is shown below.

Actual sample code: placed in path `utils/sample.py`

```
def take_input():
    response = input("please type a:")
    if response == 'a':
        return "Correct"
    return "Not Correct"
```

Actual test code:

```
from utils.sample import take_input
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestCache(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("utils.sample.input", return_value='a')
    def test_take_input(self, mock_input):
        ans = take_input()
        self.assertEqual(ans, 'Correct')
```

Take a note on how the `patch` is written and the `input` function is being called within the patch along with the specified `return_value`.

Comment: @e1630m were you able to get through with the solution?

Comment: No. I was unable to replace my current code with yours. The input file contains a random number of test cases, and each test case has a random number of inputs lines. My current code dump everything to the input and capture every printed message and then compare it to the expected output line by line basis. Not sure how to achieve this with yours.